# Is it possible to skip PHP code?

Tags: php

Just casual paranoia. Let's say we have an index.php:

```
<?php
  exit('Forbidden!');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"> 
<html>
  <title>Can you see me?</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert("Welcome!");
  </script>
  <p>You got me.</p>
</html>
```

Can an external user **somehow** reach the "Welcome!" message? And why yes/not?

Any means are valid (e.g. viewing the source code for the page).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way the PHP code could be skipped here is if the web server was misconfigured, and failed to handle a `.php` file by passing it to the PHP interpreter.  Instead it would be output as HTML, and the code would be visible by viewing the page source.

As long as the file is handled as a PHP script and the PHP code gets parsed, it will execute correctly.  There's no means of circumventing `exit()`.

Comment: I know I'm commenting on a ghost but --

If there is a **BACKUP** copy of the file on the server, with an extension like `.php~` or `.php#` then a clever person could ask for the backup file and see its contents.

Answer (score 2):

No, the page will show only "Forbidden!", if the PHP interpreter is enabled.

If it's not enabled for that file extension, though, the whole source will show (including the PHP source), however you can verify that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Normaly not ! Except if that page is somehow cached and the exit command added after the page is cached.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs page for `exit`:

> Output a message and terminate the current script

If the script is terminated then there's no way a user can ever reach the HTML part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

No, they would not be able to

"**Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit() is called.**" [php exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)